# Lumen with Eloquent arbitrary changes all fields

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

Here's the code:

```
$row = UserFields::where(['user_id' => $user['user_id'], 'field_id' => 'myfield'])->first();
if($row)
{
    $row->field_value = "new value";
    $row->save();
}
```

Suddenly all rows `field_value` in that table changes to the new value and only for that user!

That's really confusing, I don't know if it's a bug in Eloquent.

Comment: "All rows" and "only for that user" sounds a bit confusing. Can you elaborate?

Comment: What database connection you use? There ara `saving` model events?

Comment: @apokryfos The rows structure has 3 fields `user_id`, `field_id` and `field_value`, it has all users data identified by `user_id`.

Comment: @Dmitry Using MySQL

Comment: Let me rephrase that: Are (a) all 3 fields for the user `$user['user_id']` changed to "new value" or (b) all rows in the table have their `field_value` value updated to "new value"?

Comment: (b), the user has more than row in that table, so all rows with that `user_id` has been affected but only the column `field_value` who has been altered to the new value. Hope that's cleared the vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue I managed to solve this by using basic lumen db query method:

```
app('db')->update("UPDATE `xf_user_field_value` SET `field_value` = ? WHERE (user_id = ? AND field_id = ?);", [ $newValue, $user_id, $column ]);
```

I have completely disabled Eloquent as it was overkill for me and not flexible enough for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel eloquent, like many other ORMs is not good at handling composite primary keys. If you see the code it have

```
protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)
{
    $query->where($this->getKeyName(), '=', $this->getKeyForSaveQuery());

    return $query;
}
public function getKeyName()
{
    return $this->primaryKey;
}
```

since you seems to have a composite primary key it will only use the first field in it so all fields for the user will be updated.

The recommended option is to add an id field for primary key also on mapping tables or if you like me don't want to add redundant fields, you can use

```
UserFields::where(['user_id' => $user['user_id'], 'field_id' => 'myfield'])->update(['field_value', "new value"]);
```

or

```
DB::table('user_fields')->where(['user_id' => $user['user_id'], 'field_id' => 'myfield'])->update(['field_value', "new value"]);
```

Edit:

For anyone interested I did find a solution I have used before. In the model you can overload the `setKeysForSaveQuery` function like this

```
protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query) {
    $query->where('firstPKcolumn', $this->getAttribute('firstPKcolumn'))->where('otherPKcolumn', $this->getAttribute('otherPKcolumn'));

    return $query;
}
```

Then you can use `save` as normal on the model

Comment: Is there any other option? Because I'm making an API for my Xenforo forum and I can't simply change the table structure.

Comment: You can do it more manually with update(). Actually in your case I would have used UserFields::where(['user_id' => $user['user_id'], 'field_id' => 'myfield'])->update('field_value', "new value");

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick but you missed the part where you have to pass an array to that method, update your answer and I will accept it as a solution. Thanks again!

Comment: That seemed to work for a bit but after a few tries it still the same result. anyway I figured I have to use basic lumen db queries.